# How can I choose more than one translation language in Logic App?

Tags: azure-functions-core-tools

I have built in this Azure Logic app to get captions of a video. But I was wondering how can I choose multiple "Caption Languages"? Right now, the drop down lets me choose only one language for translation. But if I want to get caption language of English, Spanish, French. How can I get captions of multiple languages? What can I do to pick more than one language?

Comment: use a foreach loop https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops

Comment: @NicolasR can you please explain where exactly I would use the Foreeach loop?

Comment: on the step where you are calling for several times the same thing. So the foreach loop must contain the "Get Captions" + "Create file" operations. and why are you calling Get captions AND Get Index ? You just need Get Captions based on your question.

Comment: Hi peter, is there any update for this issue? Please check if Nicolas R's answer helps to resolve your issue. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your input, specify that you want to pass an array:

[image]

Then, get your token for VideoIndexer, and process all the array items:

[image]

There is a "for each" loop for this processing. It is doing the following steps:

- Get the captions for 1 language
- Write the result to onedrive

[image]